# How to query an alias column from a view in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

enter code hereI have created a view with few columns as Alias with blank value. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ABC_V AS
(SELECT ORG_CODE,
        CURRENCY,
        '' "ExpiryDate"
 FROM ABC
);
```

`ExpiryDate` column doesn't exist in table `ABC`
Now I want to query all the three columns value in the `select` statement to prepare a `|` delimited text file.

```
select ORG_CODE||'|'||CURRENCY||'|'||ExpiryDate
from( SELECT ORG_CODE,
             CURRENCY,
             ExpiryDate FROM ABC_V );
```

But I am getting the error

> **ORA-00904: "EXPIRYDATE": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:**

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: The mistake is that you have used double quotes on the name. Thus you tell Oracle that the column name is case sensitive. My advice: Never use double quotes when declaring names. Use underscores for readability instead: `'' AS expiry_date`. Without quotes you can select the column thus: `select expiry_date ...` and thus: `select EXPIRY_DATE ...` and thus: `select ExPiRy_DaTe ...` - the column is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

As you enclosed ExpiryDate into double quotes, you **must** do so - following exactly the same letter case - **always** you reference it.

So:

```
SELECT ORG_CODE || '|' || CURRENCY || '|' || "ExpiryDate"
  FROM (SELECT ORG_CODE, CURRENCY, "ExpiryDate" FROM ABC_V);
```

---

A better option: dismiss double quotes while working with Oracle and do as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW abc_v
AS
   SELECT org_code, currency, '' expirydate FROM abc;

SELECT org_code || '|' || currency || '|' || expirydate FROM abc_v;
```

(no need for a subquery).

Answer (score 0):

He re is how you can do it without the error:

```
select ORG_CODE || '|' || CURRENCY || '|' || "ExpiryDate"
from( SELECT ORG_CODE
             , CURRENCY
             , "ExpiryDate" 
      FROM ABC_V );
```

Here is a demo:

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=33de0a66dfc9b745620c52035b2a16b7)

Answer (score 0):

No need to create an extra  view to *add such dummy column* (starting with 11g).

You may use a *virtual column* directly on the table

```
alter table tab add (
  "ExpiryDate" DATE as (NULL)
);
```

You may query the table with your new column (but rememder the double quotetd colun name preserve the case with it was defined!)

```
SELECT ORG_CODE,
        CURRENCY,
        "ExpiryDate"
 FROM tab;
```